# Why can't I turn on 'metered connection' for Ethernet in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, wired-networking

I have been using Windows 10 since last 4 years. I have a Windows 10 (Pro) PC and one Windows 10 (Home) edition. But I have seen something peculiar in both of them while connecting to the internet via my phone using a USB cable.

I am running out of space and to prevent automatic downloads of updates, I keep my wi-fi connection 'metered'. But the problem arises when I connect to the internet via cables. I can't set the connection as 'metered'. As soon as I toggle the switch to **Turn ON** the 'metered connection' option as shown:
[image: Here I turned it "ON"]

> And come back later during the browsing session to see if it's still 'metered', I get this:

[image: It's automatically 'turned off']

So, here it is, Metered connection automatically toggled **'OFF'**.

I have been facing this issue since my first version of Windows 10 v1703. Since I could manage with Wi-fi previously, so I didn't pay much heed towards this, but as I am switching on to the wired internet, this needs to be fixed. 
If someone knows how to fix it, it would be of great help.

I am currently on Windows 10 v1709 (Home edition).

[P.S.: Questions have been asked about 'metered connection' issues on this platform, but none of them address **this particular issue.** , so I considered asking it here after searching on the WEB and not getting anything fruitful.]

Comment: You can not designate all connections as metered. Do you have another Ethernet connection configured?

Comment: I use my mobile phone with 4G internet for connecting to the web. The problem occurs while connecting it via USB cable for 'USB tethering'.
I never connected any LAN cable to my laptop yet.

Comment: If Wi-Fi did work before why are you switching?

Comment: For faster speed @Seth.

Comment: @Sanu_012 - I suspect the issue is with Windows 10 version 1709 itself.  I strongly advise you to upgrade to one of the supported versions of Windows 10 and see if the problem is solved.  *I can confirm I can enable this setting on all connections to my PC.*

Comment: @Ramhound he can as well. It's just "revoked" some time later. Might be because there is a short connection issue or similar.

Comment: Unless your 2.4 GHz band is pretty "full" you shouldn't have issue reaching sufficient speed. Especially if you're using a mobile. As Ramhound said freeing some space and updating Windows might be a good idea.

Comment: @Seth - The author does not provide any sort of timeframe for the behavior to surface.  So I can't test the behavior of my system.

Comment: @Ramhound Speaking about the time frame - when I enable the 'metered connection' button and close it just to check it back again in seconds, it's already there, changed back to 'disabled' mode.

Comment: @Sanu_012 - That is the exact test I performed.  You really should upgrade your Windows 10 installation to a supported version of Windows 10,

Comment: I just tried this fix: https://www.askvg.com/tip-force-windows-10-to-use-ethernet-connection-as-metered/
Didn't work for me.

Comment: The new update is more than 6 GB, I can't let windows take so much of space. Btw, can you turn on the 'metered connection' forever in your version of windows 10? What version are you using? @Ramhound

Comment: @Sanu_012 - Yes;  I can do exactly that;  I am using `Windows 10 version 1909`.  You can download the ISO then create an installation disk, and from within Windows, perform the upgrade.  You still need free space to do this, but you can delete the ISO, once you have the installation media.

Comment: I do know how to update but I really don't want to. Are we not left with any other options? Why this didn't work: https://www.askvg.com/tip-force-windows-10-to-use-ethernet-connection-as-metered/ ? Any idea about that? In-fact, I have changed the DWORD value to 2 for ethernet, yet not able to restrict automatic update downloads.

Comment: The other solution is to just not use a network connection or the WLAN connection as that is working for you. Installing Windows updates is a good idea in general. If you need long term support you'd need something like the LTSB/LTSC version which isn't available to regular consumers as far as I know.

Comment: USB tethering doesn't allow me to set 'metered-connection'. I never tried a LAN cable with my laptop, but I think both are categorized under Ethernet, right? So, perhaps connecting a LAN cable will not fetch some different result and i will still not be able to set 'metered-connection' on it. Sad me.

Comment: Hello everyone, I have found a workaround for this issue. I have posted it as an answer. Thank you all for lending me a helping hand and made me learn something more yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here I am with a workaround for this persistent issue. Some more browsing through the internet led me to this solution. I wasn't sure if it would exactly work or not,  but I went to the registry editor (made a backup first), and then started applying the workaround.

After logging in to the registry editor as Administrator, went to this adress:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost
```

then took 'full control access' to that particular registry key. Changed the DWORD value for ethernet to **2**. And then hit a quick restart.

Then I checked if the problem persists, and *to my surprise, **it was still there.*** With confusion all around, I continued using the internet via the Ethernet connection mode, and expected the PC to suck out all my data. ***But to my pleasant surprise***, *my PC wasn't using any of the data to download the updates,* so, essentially it started behaving as a 'metered connection'.

So, even if I still couldn't turn on the 'metered connection' option, the connection was not 'unmetered' any more. It just saved me from downloading the updates, with some other shitty bug contained within.

For more information, you can visit this link and see how it's done:
https://www.askvg.com/tip-force-windows-10-to-use-ethernet-connection-as-metered/